# Send keys not working in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

send keys are not working in selenium with python.
This was working earlier but it fails now.
I don't know what may be the issue . It gives following error :

```
u"Element is disabled and so may not be used
for actions\nCommand duration or timeout: 11             
milliseconds\nBuild info: version: '2.15.0', revision: '15105', time:
'2011-12-08   09:56:25'\nSystem info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
'amd64', os.version: '6.1',    java.version: '1.6.0_22'
```

I have used below along with `time.sleep(3)` before passing keys

```
elem.send_keys('selenium')   
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Also

```
elem.send_keys("Sale" + Keys.RETURN)
```

But nothing works

Comment: Fix formatting and grammar, why is everything a block quote?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the element is `disabled` and hence you(a user using a browser, selenium tries to mimic such a user) can not interact with that element.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this also. `find_element_by_*` returns a list. A quick fix is to use the first element, i.e. `elem[0].send_keys(text)`.