# find_element_by_id().send_keys() is sending a character by character but not the whole string at a time in IE

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, pycharm

I want to send the string "abcd" at a time into the search box and then want to click on the search button but `find_element_by_id().send_keys()` is sending character by character and taking more time to get the string searched.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

from selenium import webdriver

path = raw_input()

def retrieve(path):

 wb = load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb.active

    alist, blist, clist, dlist   = []
    for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
        for cell in row:
            alist.append(cell.value)
    for row in ws.iter_rows('B{}:B{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
        for cell in row:
            blist.append(cell.value)

    for row in ws.iter_rows('C{}:C{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
        for cell in row:
            clist.append(cell.value)

    for row in ws.iter_rows('D{}:D{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
        for cell in row:
            dlist.append(cell.value)
    driver = webdriver.Ie()
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
    for i in range(0,alist.__len__()):
        driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys(alist[i])
        driver.find_element_by_id("_fZl").submit()
retrieve(path)
```

where my excel sheet will be having 4 columns from where I need to get string from A1 cell and search in search box in my application and then fill data from b1,c1,d1 cells and then search for A2 cell.....

could you please let me know how to send the whole string at a time .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
As your sample code dont't show what about B,C,D values i guess joining it.

```
# Get Data from all rows
for row in ws.rows:
    A_value = row[:1][0].value
    # Join columen B,C,D values without spacing
    BCD_value = ''.join(cell.value for cell in row[1:5])

    print('A_value=%s, BCD_value=%s' % (A_value, BCD_value))
    # Do your work with this rows Data
    # ...
    driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib").send_keys( A_value )
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1***
Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.

Comment: Hi, it still sending character by character. could you please check once again. B,C,D are column names of Excel from where I need to get data and process after searching the string value from A column of excel sheet.

Comment: @user62 Does A_value show the full String you want to send?

Comment: Read This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007339/send-keys-not-working-in-selenium-with-python and This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564539/selenium-webdriver-sendkeys-using-python-and-firefox

Comment: Yes, stovfl, a[i] is showing the string value, I want to send

Comment: As I read in the docs `.send_keys() ` simulates a users Keyboard Input so the behavior char by char could be desired by design.